# Can I set a cron for deleting and re-indexing Search API daily?

Tags: commerce, cron, search

Using Commerce Kickstart 2.

When we add new products, the facet search index does not re-index automatically as it says it does (Maybe because we are using some Aggregated Fields?) -Whatever-, we have to re-build the index manually to get certain search fields to work.

I read a bit and it -seems- as though the standard cron tasks -should- add to the index, but that ain't happening.

So: Is there a way to create an 'Re-build Index' to a list of nightly Cron jobs?

Answer (score 0):

If you have Drush on your server, you can use the `drush search-api-reindex` command. This way you don't need to invoke a cron, but can force a reindex.

Note: You'll need to run `drush search-api-list` first to get the numeric identifier for the index when you run the re-index command.

Reference more info here: http://drushcommands.com/drush-6x/search-api/search-api-reindex